# No collection being created in Mongo Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

```
This is my .js file that contains the routes .


var express = require("express");
    var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
    var router = express.Router();
    var passport = require("passport");

    //User model
    var User = require("../models/StudentUser.js");
    router.post("/studentRegister",(req,res) =>
    {
        const {username,password,phone_no,student_id,dob,school,batch}=req.body;
        let errors = [];
        if(!student_id|| !username || !password || !phone_no || !dob || !school || !batch ){
        errors.push({msg:"Please fill in all fields."});
        }
        if(errors.length>0)
        {
            res.render("../views/signupStudent.ejs",{
                errors,
                username,
                password,
                phone_no,
                student_id,
                dob,
                school,
                batch
            });
        }
        else{
            var newUser = new User({
                username,
                password,
                phone_no,
                student_id,
                dob,
                school,
                batch
            });
            newUser.save(function(err)
   {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }
       else
       {
        res.redirect("../views/dashboard.ejs");
       console.log("success");
       }
   });
        }


    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Following is the schema I created:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose= require("passport-local-mongoose");

var StudentUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    student_id:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    phone_no:{
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    dob:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now

    },
    school:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    batch:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
StudentUserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = User =  mongoose.model("User",StudentUserSchema);
```

I have used console.log(newUser) in my file to check if the new user details have been updated but nothing is displayed. No collection is being created in my Atlas Cluster either. The MongoDB connection is confirmed but there is no progress further. The error handling doesn't work either and no error is thrown.

Please ignore the error handling aspect of my code for now. My major concern is to make sure that a collection is being created corresponding to the schema in my cluster(the key api to which I have correctly included as the connection is confirmed). Thank You!

Comment: Try checking for any error on `newUser.save();` & wait at that point till it gets finished..